# SQLite3 and Tkinter Python: adding or subtracting values in a Database based on user input

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite

I have created a ATM GUI program using Tkinter and using python's sqlite3 as a way to store Account Numbers, Pin Numbers and the Balance for a persons Checking and Savings Account. I am having issues manipulating the data for the Checking Account, and the Savings account. Before without an SQL database, the way I set my program up is that I have lists called `checkAmnt, saveAmnt, and balanceAmnt`, with starting values of 5000.00, 1000,00 and 6000.00 respectively. So if I wanted to add or remove money I would either append the specified list with a number ie: -20.00 for withdrawing $20 or 1000.00 for depositing or transferring. Then I would  write a script to get the balance:

```
 for _ in checkAmnt:
            check_balance = float(sum(checkAmnt))
```

Now I am trying to do the same thing but modify my script to work with SQLite3. So I wrote a function that has a Login Page and when you login it pulls the values associated with the specific account number.

```
 def log_check(self):

        def get_account_number(): 
            actNum = int(act_num_entry.get())
            return actNum
        def get_pin_number():
            pinNum = int(pin_num_entry.get())
            return pinNum   
        con = sqlite3.connect('bank_accounts.db')    
        c = con.cursor()
        def start_checkAmnt():        
            sql_chk = ("SELECT CHECKING FROM Account WHERE Account = ?",(get_account_number(),))
            c.execute(*sql_chk)
            chk = c.fetchone()
            start_checkAmnt=list(chk)
            return start_checkAmnt
        def start_saveAmnt():
            sql_sve = ("SELECT SAVINGS FROM Account WHERE Account = ?",(get_account_number(),))
            c.execute(*sql_sve)
            sve = c.fetchone()
            start_saveAmnt=list(sve)
            return start_saveAmnt
        def start_balance():
            sql_bal=("SELECT BALANCE FROM Account WHERE Account = ?",(get_account_number(),))
            c.execute(*sql_bal)
            bal = c.fetchone()
            balanceAmnt=list(bal)
            return balanceAmnt  
        def get_dbActNum():
            try:
                sqla = ("SELECT ACCOUNT FROM Account WHERE ACCOUNT = ?", (get_account_number(),))
                c.execute(*sqla)
                dbActNum = c.fetchone()
                return dbActNum
            except:
                pass
        def get_dbPinNum():
            try:
                sqlp = ("SELECT PIN FROM Account WHERE Account = ?", (get_account_number(),))
                c.execute(*sqlp)
                dbPinNum = c.fetchone() 
                return dbPinNum
            except:
                pass

        try:
            if get_account_number() in get_dbActNum() and get_pin_number() in get_dbPinNum():
# This next part creates a database login which I use to use as a check for when I prompt the user to Re-login to complete another trnsaction
                con = sqlite3.connect('login.db')    
                c = con.cursor()
                c.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reloginCheck")
                c.execute("CREATE TABLE reloginCheck(Account INT, PIN_Num INT)")
                c.execute("INSERT INTO reloginCheck VALUES(?,?)", (get_account_number(), get_pin_number()))
                con.commit() 
                tm.showinfo("ATM Login", "Login Successful")
                self.controller.show_frame(WelcomePage)
            else:
                tm.showerror("Login Error", "Invalid Entry")
        except UnboundLocalError and TypeError:
            tm.showerror("Login Error", "Can't Find Account")
            self.controller.show_frame(LogIn)
            pass
```

This script works but I am having trouble calling `get_account_number()`and `start_saveAmnt`in my other classes like my Checking Withdraw or Savings Withdraw because they are in my function `log_check()` which is in a Class called `LogIn()` I tried `LogIn.log_check().get_account_number()` Before I declared global variables which worked but now they do not. Can I modify my buttons and entry fields to automatically subtract or add to the checking or savings account in the database without having to use a lists. Can I call a function within a function that is in a different Class. How can I modify my checking account based on a specific account number the user has entered throughout my other classes without using global variables.

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are in a class named `LogIn`, presumably  you have an instance of that class somewhere (eg: `loginPage = LogIn(...)`). To call the functions you just need to use the instance (eg: `loginPage.log_check()`)

However, most of your functions are local to the `log_check` function, so there's simply no way to call them outside of that `log_check`. If you need to call them from other places, make them methods of the object rather than functions embedded inside other functions.

Comment: I tried that but LogIn class is a tkinter Frame and it gives me a ton of TypeErrors. Here is my code `class LogIn(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller`

Comment: My mistake. I didn't realize those were embedded functions. Why are you using embedded functions?  I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have a Tkinter Frame Class called `LogIn`. Within the frame there is a "Login Button" which runs my `log_check(self)` function. Before I used global variables to be able to access variables outside my `log_check` function like the account number entry and pin number entry fields. I used embedded functions to get rid of the use of global variables. I also thought but using another function I would be able to get the Account Number the user used to login. Without those I wouldn't be able to get the Account Number to retrieve the Checking Account Balance